Expansion of $e^x$
Find constants $A_1, A_2, A_3, A_4$ that $e^x=\frac{1+A_1x+A_2x^2}{1+A_3x+A_4x^2}+o(x^2)$ for $x\rightarrow0$.
I know that $e^x=1+x+\frac{x^2}{2}+o(x^2)$, so should I just pick $A_1=1,A_2=\frac{1}{2},A_3=0,A_4=0$? I guess it's too easy haha

That looks fine. A silly question, I would say.

Your solution is correct. Can you find all the solutions?

Just for your interest: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pad%C3%A9_approximant

I suspect a typo. Whoever asked this question really wanted $o(x^4)$, when following Gary's link gives you the idea.

Alternatively, see this old thread.

Okay, thank you all! I guess all solutions are $(A_1,A_2,A_3,A_4)=(1+A_3,\frac{1}{2}+A_3+A_4,A_3,A_4)$

https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=PadeApproximant%5BExp%5Bx%5D%2C+%7Bx%2C+0%2C+%7B2%2C+2%7D%7D%5D

To approxiomate $e^x$ by $P/Q$ to the second order near $x = 0$, where $P(0) = 1$, $Q(0) = 1$ match $P = Q e^x$. Setting $Q(x) = 1 + ax + bx^2$, and using $e^x = 1 + x + ½x^2 + o(x^2)$, then:
$$\begin{align}
P(x)
&= (1 + ax + bx^2)(1 + x + ½x^2) + o(x^2)\\
&= 1 + (1 + a)x + (½ + a + b)x^2 + o(x^2).
\end{align}$$
Thus
$$e^x = \frac{1 + (1 + a)x + (½ + a + b)x^2}{1 + ax + bx^2} + o(x^2).$$
A similar exercise matching to $o(x^4)$ determines $a = -½$, $b = 1/12$, $1 + a = ½$ and $½ + a + b = 1/12$. Thus
$$e^x = \frac{1 + ½x + x^2/12}{1 - ½x + x^2/12} + o(x^4).$$
Edit:
We can go two orders higher:
$$e^x = \frac{1 + ½x + x^2/10 + x^3/120}{1 - ½x + x^2/10 - x^3/120} + o(x^6).$$

thank u so much!
